# ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer not rendered in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, html-safe

Very simple question really, but it's driving me nuts.

I have this method call in a Rails view:

```
<%= get_image(@document) %>
```

The method in here returns an object of type `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`. If I call `.to_str` on it in a console, I see the expected result (just an html img tag). However, when I stick the above code in a view, there's nothing there. Just an empty string.

If I do this:

```
<%= get_image(@document).to_str %>
```

in an effort to convert the `SafeBuffer` into a `String` object, I see the literal HTML in the page, and not the image tag.

I feel like I'm missing something simple or elementary here. Can anyone point the way? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: since it's been requested, here's what the `get_image` method looks like:

```
def get_image(document)
  document[document.type+'.image'].nil? ? nil : document[document.type+'.image'].as_html_safe
end
```

Comment: show the method body of `get_image`.

Comment: bitops, given the console has the text, and using #to_str in erb shows the literal html, it seems it really is a SafeBuffer that should be output into the code. A tag wouldn't show on the rendered page, but are you certain it isn't in the html source code?

Comment: @ArupRakshit the content of the get_image method is really irrelevant as far as I've been able to determine.

Comment: @BrianMurphy-Dye I have checked and I am certain that the html is not there.

Comment: That is truly weird! Is this rendered if you add this in the same place? <%= '<p style="font-size: 50">am i rendered?</p>'.html_safe %> -- that too should be a SafeBuffer.

Comment: @bitops I wanted to see how you are creating an object of `SafeBuffer` class. and also wanted to see if it is `html_safe` or not.

Comment: @BrianMurphy-Dye will give it a shot, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ArupRakshit it is coming from a library I am using. Calling `html_safe?` on it returns true.

Comment: @BrianMurphy-Dye just tried it out and it does work -- it's rendered correctly.

Comment: @BrianMurphy-Dye here is something I just noticed -- when I call `to_str` the reason the HTML is showing up as literal text is because it is wrapped in double quotes!

Comment: Does get_image(@document).class return SafeBuffer and get_image(@document).to_str.class return String?

Comment: @BrianMurphy-Dye yep, that's what they return.

Comment: You mentioned that `to_str` against your get_image call has double quotes around it. Does this also have double quotes around it:  '<p style="font-size: 50">am i rendered?</p>'.html_safe.to_s? Also, what exactly does the get_image call give you?